# Remove the left sidebar in shinydashboardPlus (keep only the right)

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is it possible to completely remove the left `sidebar` in `shinydashboardPlus` but keep the right?

I have tried omitting the call to the argument `sidebar` but this argument is required so I get an error. What I would like is to achieve this (no left sidebar only a right one).

[image]

**Example code**

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
data(iris)

header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
  rightSidebarIcon = "filter"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(selectInput(inputId = "slect",
                                        label = "Selection Menu", 
                                        selected = "a",
                                        choices = LETTERS[1:3])
)

body <- dashboardBody(fluidPage(plotOutput( "scatter", 
                                  height = "700px", 
                                  width = "700px")))

rightsidebar <- rightSidebar()

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(header, 
                        sidebar, 
                        body, 
                        rightsidebar)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, pch=21)
      cats <- levels(iris$Species)
      cols <- c("red", "blue", "yellow2")
      ind <- lapply(cats, function(z) which(iris$Species == z))
      for (i in seq(cats)) {
        points(iris$Petal.Length[ind[[i]]], iris$Petal.Width[ind[[i]]], 
               pch = 19, col = cols[i])
      }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Session info:

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shinydashboardPlus_0.7.5 shinydashboard_0.7.1     shinyWidgets_0.5.3       dendextend_1.13.4       
 [5] tidyr_1.1.0              patchwork_1.0.1          ggplot2_3.3.1            shinyhelper_0.3.2       
 [9] colorspace_1.4-1         colourpicker_1.0         shinythemes_1.1.2        DT_0.13                 
[13] shiny_1.4.0.2            dplyr_1.0.0              MSnbase_2.14.2           ProtGenerics_1.20.0     
[17] S4Vectors_0.26.1         mzR_2.22.0               Rcpp_1.0.4.6             Biobase_2.48.0          
[21] BiocGenerics_0.34.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry short on time right now, but please check this regarding your 1st question:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
data(iris)

header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
  rightSidebarIcon = "filter"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = "0px"
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidPage(plotOutput( "scatter",
                        height = "700px", 
                        width = "700px")))

rightsidebar <- rightSidebar()

ui <- tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPagePlus(header, 
                        sidebar, 
                        body, 
                        rightsidebar))

server <- function(input, output) {
  hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, pch=21)
    cats <- levels(iris$Species)
    cols <- c("red", "blue", "yellow2")
    ind <- lapply(cats, function(z) which(iris$Species == z))
    for (i in seq(cats)) {
      points(iris$Petal.Length[ind[[i]]], iris$Petal.Width[ind[[i]]], 
             pch = 19, col = cols[i])
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you @ismirsehregal Works perfectly for the 1st question. Fingers crossed you or someone else can help with question 2!

Comment: Btw. why don't you split it up in 2 separate questions. Makes it easier for future readers.

Comment: I would usually have done this but recent feedback from SO suggested I try not and ask too many similar questions so I have been hesitant!

Comment: Of course, I don't know about this recent feedback - but in this case splitting up makes sense to me.

Comment: Also @ismirsehregal related to the above, do you perhaps know how to solve [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837262/is-it-possible-to-fix-the-left-and-right-sidebars-in-shinydashboardplus-to-perma) please?