# Is it possible to fix the left and right sidebars in shinydashboardPlus to permanently be open?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is it possible to fix the left and right sidebars in `shinydashboardPlus` to permanently be open and disable the functionality to hide them?

I have seen some ways using JS or css to [have them open on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756854/right-sidebar-open-by-default-in-shinydashboardplus) but not to keep permanently open.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
      background = "dark",
      rightSidebarTabContent(
        id = 1,
        title = "Tab 1",
        icon = "desktop",
        active = TRUE,
        sliderInput(
          "obs",
          "Number of observations:",
          min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
        )
      )
    ),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shinyjs_1.1              shinydashboardPlus_0.7.5 shinydashboard_0.7.1     shinyWidgets_0.5.3      
 [5] dendextend_1.13.4        tidyr_1.1.0              patchwork_1.0.1          ggplot2_3.3.1           
 [9] shinyhelper_0.3.2        colorspace_1.4-1         colourpicker_1.0         shinythemes_1.1.2       
[13] DT_0.13                  shiny_1.4.0.2            dplyr_1.0.0              MSnbase_2.14.2          
[17] ProtGenerics_1.20.0      S4Vectors_0.26.1         mzR_2.22.0               Rcpp_1.0.4.6            
[21] Biobase_2.48.0           BiocGenerics_0.34.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After forcing the `rightSidebar` to be opened on startup it should be sufficient to hide the toggle button to keep it open:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = tags$body(class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open", dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$script(HTML(
        '$("body > div > header > nav > div:nth-child(4) > ul > li > a").hide();
         document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-toggle")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";'
      )),
    ),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
      background = "dark",
      rightSidebarTabContent(
        id = 1,
        title = "Tab 1",
        icon = "desktop",
        active = TRUE,
        sliderInput(
          "obs",
          "Number of observations:",
          min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
        )
      )
    ),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Here is how you can copy the selector of the element (after rightclick, inspect) using google chrome:
[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760263/disable-right-sidebar-ability-at-all-for-a-specific-tab-of-a-shiny-dashboard) you can find a related question (hiding the element on the server side).

Comment: just reading back over this having been away for a few weeks and see your solution only fixes the right sidebar. How can I fix both the left and right please? Could you update your solution and add comment lines to the css to make clear?

Comment: Sorry - seems I was reading your question too fast. Please see my edit.